# Why does my regex not work?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have several lines of phrases like

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Now I want to select the rest of each line after every first word. I.e. I want to mark everything starting from the end of the first word in a line.
My attempt was:

```
^(?:\w+).*
```

I'm using this in Notepad++.
Why does this select the entire line? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for improving my Regex knowledge!

Comment: https://regex101.com/ will be very helpful in debugging this, give it a try!

Comment: Oh thanks, that looks helpful indeed. Already improved my regex to `^(?:\w+).*$` (which doesn't solve the problem though)

Comment: `{1}` is unnecessary, `\w` alone matches once by default

Comment: I just realized that, and it actually makes it worse: it says it matches one word character, but I want to skip the full word. So I changed it back to +

Comment: So first line should be `quick brown....` second `brown fox....` and the last `fox jumps...`?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\h+(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \S+       # 1 or more non space (you van use \w+ if you want to replace ONLY word characters)
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (.+)      # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

---

Here is an explanation of your regex:

```
^           # beginning of line
  (?:       # start non capture group
    \w+     # 1 or more word character
  )         # end group
  .*        # 0 or more any character
```

So, it matches a word and every thing after this word. The non capture group is useless here. A non capture group doesn't mean that will not match but only that will not be captured. It is strictly equivalent to: `^\w+.*`

Comment: That's great, and it works! I'd like to accept the answer but the question I asked was "why doesn't it work". Is there an explanation for why the non-capturing \w+ doesn't work? I do understand your solution, which is great, I just don't understand yet why mine doesn't work.

Comment: @Doidel: I have added an explanation, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a zero-width positive lookbehind with `\K`, e.g.:

```
^\w+[^\w]+\K.*
```

The `\w+` would match the first word at the beginning of the line (`The` or `quick`), the following space character would be matched by `[^\w]+` (one or more non-word characters). And `\K.*` matches everything after that, not including anything before the `\K` into the match.

It's described in the perl documentation: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions

You regex doesn't work, because you're matching the beginning of the line, followed by one or more word-characters (doesn't matter if you use the non-capturing group `(?:…)` here or not), followed by any characters. The problem is, that the word-characters at the beginning of the line `^(?:\w+)` (same as `^\w+`) are part of your match.

Comment: It works, great! Thanks! However I just explained in the other post that I don't know yet why mine doesn't work and yours does. Without understanding why my approach fails, it's too early for me to accept an answer.

Comment: @Doidel Added a short explanation. No problem, take your time. Maybe there are more working answers to come.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!